# Jumping increases movement speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game with ball physics and an FPS camera. I have this bug where the player's movement is increased when I jump.

Example:

Running along the Z axis on a plane:

[image: z axis speed is ~3.75]

Suddenly jumping:

[image: z speed increases to 5, it actually got higher]

My code:

```
void Update()
{
    // Input
    moveFwrd = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    moveSide = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    // Player Jump
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(jumpKey) && Physics.Raycast(
            transform.position,
            Vector3.down,
            DistanceToTheGround + 0.1f))
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    // Braking
    if (Input.GetKey(brakeKey))
    {
        rb.angularDrag = brakeForce;
    }
    else
    {
        rb.angularDrag = 0.01f;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Player Movement
    Vector3 movement = cam.transform.right * moveFwrd +
                       cam.transform.forward * moveSide;

    movement = movement.normalized;

    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the answer is [friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction). Depending on the [physics material](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) used for the player's [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) collider and the physics material used for the floor, the Rigidbody will behave differently:

[image: screenshot of inspector dialog of physics material from the Unity documentation]

Static friction describes the friction when both objects are not moving (i.e. before the player starts moving), dynamic/kinetic/sliding friction describes the friction when the player is moving along/on the floor. It will also determine if the rigidbody slides or rolls on the floor, you could experiment with different physics materials to see the effects.

The reason why you see faster movement in mid-air in forward direction after pressing the jump button is that the Rigidbody is no longer affected by "contact friction" between solid materials while airborne, hence it will move faster with the same applied forward force. - However, there's still friction involved: air resistance; which can be controlled by `Rigidbody.drag` and `Rigidbody.angularDrag`.

If you want to get rid of this simulated bahavior, you could do various things: Use different physics materials, `Rigidbody.drag`, `Rigidbody.mass` values, or try to experiment with a different [ForceMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html) like `ForceMode.VelocityChange` arguments in `Rigidbody.AddForce()`. Or do not use the physics engine and rigidbodies at all for motion (colliders and raycasts can still be used).

Side notes:

`FixedUpdate()` is called at regular intervals, and is the recommended place to do physics related scripting. It is actually called at the same frequency as the internal physics engine is updated, like [documented here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html). The duration between every call is constant: `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

`Update()` on the other hand is called at a variable rate, and has a variable duration `Time.deltaTime`, which results in different frame rates (FPS). This method can be used for the visual rendering or state processing of the game, and should not be used to update physics related stuff if possible.

In the script above, you use `Rigidbody.AddForce()` in both methods `Update()` and `FixedUpdate()`. In the latter with the default argument `ForceMode.Force` and in the other case with `ForceMode.Impulse`. In both cases you do not take the frame time into account, which is fine in the case of an [impulse](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html), applied once (after a key has been pressed). In the other case the direction vector gets normalized, so it isn't really a problem either, because the method is called at a fixed rate... but it could be written a bit more clearly.